# Productivity Power Tools 2017/2019 extension stops copy operation in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-2017-build-tools, productivity-power-tools

I'm using Visual Studio 2017. After installing Productivity Power Tools 2017/2019 extension, I can't use the copy operation. The first time I try to copy a line or block of code after installing the extension, Visual Studio generates an error saying:

> "Type library exporter encountered an error while processing
> 'CopyAsHtml.CopyAsHtmlPackage, CopyAsHtml'. Error: Type library
> exporter encountered an error while processing
> 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.SVsSolutionObject,
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop'. Error: Type 'SVsSolutionObject'
> and type 'SVsSolution' both have the sameUUID."

Next time onwards, whenever I try to copy, Visual Studio generates the error saying:

> "Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004005 (E_FAIL))"

When I uninstall Productivity Power Tools 2017/2019, there's no error message and I can copy everything properly. It seems, the problem is with the extension. So, is there a way to fix the problem so that I can use Productivity Power Tools 2017/2019 and not encounter the problem at the same time? Or shall I have to give up using Productivity Power Tools 2017/2019 entirely and continue Visual Studio without it?

Regards

Comment: Turn off the copy as HTML feature in the Power Tools.

Comment: Yeah right, that seems to be the root of the problem. Disabling/uninstalling Copy As Html solves the issue. Thanks for pointing it out. Appreciate your help.